# cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall *)(HWND,const wchar_t,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'

Tags: c++, window

### Error:

I was running through [this](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-1-3) tutorial on window creation, and have come across the error:

```
Error 1 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall *)(HWND,const wchar_t,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'
```

### Question:

What going wrong here? Is this tutorial outdated or something of the sort?

### Code:

The code is identical or nearly identical to that of the tutorial.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "windowsx.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                            const wchar_t message,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    //Handle for the window, filled by a function
    HWND hWnd;

    //This struct holds information for the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    //Clear out the window class 
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    //Fill struct with needed information
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Window Class";

    //Register the window class
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //Create the window to use as a handle
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(  NULL,
                            "Window Class",
                            "Our first window",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                            300,
                            300,
                            500,
                            400,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            hInstance,
                            NULL);

    ShowWindow( hWnd,
                nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

//Main message handler
static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                            const wchar_t message,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam)
{
    //Find the code to run for the message
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            //Close the app entirely
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } break;
    }

    //Handle any messages the switch didn't
    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: While a `wchar_t` might have used to be identical in some compilers, not anymore. I actually think MSVC has a compiler option for it being a distinct type. And keep in mind that if you go through that tutorial, you should be furiously reading MSDN and checking errors properly. The tutorial doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. I had to change much of the code given in the tutorial from `L"foo"` to just `"foo"` because I received an error saying that `UINT` could not be converted to `const wchar_t`, and so without thinking I changed `UINT` to `const wchar_t` in my function declaration. Your comment explains why the tutorial had this error, +1.

Answer (score 0):

The declarations `const wchar_t message` should be replaced with `UINT`. This error is received because of faulty parameters.